# libgit2 checkout does not update the head

Tags: git, libgit2

I have a git repo with 2 branches, master and foo. The master branch commit has 3 files (1.txt,2.txt,3.txt), the foo branch commit has removed the 3.txt.

I 'm calling git_checkout_tree with the id of the commit the foo branch points to, and the 3.txt file is indeed removed. However the head is not set to point to foo, it still points to master, and git status says "D 3.txt".

What am I missing? How do I update the head to point to foo? I guess it has something to do with the libgit2 reference API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The checkout functions are about checking out files to the worktree, as indicated by the description of the function

> Updates files in the index and working tree to match the content of the tree pointed at by the treeish.

The checkout family of function have nothing to do with git's `checkout` command's branch-switching mode. In order to change, what the active branch is, you need to make HEAD point to that branch, either via the generic `git_reference_*` functions, or the `git_repository_set_head()` convenience function helper.